# How to design a good and nice GUI for an Android application?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am designing a dialer pad application . In GUI I am using `Button,ImageButton EditText, TextView` As Android provide by default framework for them.

I want to show Buttons look  as we look in web designing.

Please tell me on which tool using we give a good GUI.

May i take the help of Adobe Photoshop foe designing these buttons or

Android provide any default tools to do that.

Please Help me.

Thanks
Anshu

Comment: Ask programming related question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can design anything and as we want. we need to use Images properly. Use ImageView as a Button . or change the background of button on its click.. there are so many ways

Comment: if any answer helps you out accept it by checking the arrow on left side so that other can get a benefit of that